# jquery code painfully slow in chrome

Tags: jquery

I have made this for one of my clients

http://clients.joompros.com/slideshow/default.php

however - i am having performance issues , specially in chrome - can anyone please offer any insights ? Or something specific which may be causing it ?

I am using supersized2 plugin ( modified ).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It runs about the same for me in Chrome and Firefox, on OS X.  The display, however, doesn't look right, as it does not scale the image in the background; I oonly see the top left corner of the image, and the thumbnail bar is rendered wrong in both.

If there is a problem, it may be with the supersized plugin. jquery itself usually runs very well in chrome.

Comment: yes - i know that jquery is not the problem .. i was wondering if someone can sopt the problem in supersize plugin .. i teriied a lot , but can't find it ...

Answer (score 0):

A new JavaScript Engine has hit the pavement running: The new V8 engine (powering the brand-new Google Chrome browser).

There are now a ton of JavaScript engines on the market (even when you only look at the ones being actively used in browsers):

1. JavaScriptCore: The engine that powers Safari/WebKit (up until Safari 3.1).
2. SquirrelFish: The engine used by Safari 4.0. Note: The latest WebKit nightly for Windows crashes on Dromaeo, so it's passed for now.
3. V8: The engine used by Google Chrome.
4. SpiderMonkey: The engine that powers Firefox (up to, and including, Firefox 3.0).
5. TraceMonkey: The engine that will power Firefox 3.1 and newer (currently in nightlies, but disabled by default).
6. Futhark: The engine used in Opera 9.5 and newer.
7. IE JScript: The engine that powers Internet Explorer.

There have, already, been a number of performance tests run on the above browsers - and a few of those runs have also included the new Chrome browser. It's important to look at these numbers and try and gain some perspective on what the tests are testing and how those numbers relate to actual web page performance.

We have three test suites that we're going to look at:

```
* SunSpider: The popular JavaScript performance test suite released by the WebKit team. Tests only the performance of the JavaScript engine (no rendering or DOM manipulation). Has a wide variety of tests (objects, function calls, math, recursion, etc.)
* V8 Benchmark: A benchmark built by the V8 team, only tests JavaScript performance - with a heavy emphasis on testing the performance of recursion.
* Dromaeo: A test suite built by Mozilla, tests JavaScript, DOM, and JavaScript Library performance. Has a wide variety of tests, with the majority of time spent analyzing DOM and JavaScript library performance.
```